# Search for value in javascript document inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, document

I'm a bit lost regarding how exactly should I retrieve a value of a javascript array of documents. So, I have the following:

```
var array = [];
//example of content inside 'array' 
//array = [{key1: value1},{key2:value2}...]
```

I have a certain **key**. What I'd like to do is search through *array* and get the value that is unique to the certain **key** I have. How can I do this, and most importantly, **since I'm constantly removing and adding new key:value pairs as javascript objects**, is it better for me to use an array as above or instead array = {} and add keys:values there? Thank you for your help

Comment: any particular reason why you can't just use a dict? `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ..}`

Comment: @MightyPork I actually need to use the array now that I think of it... can you help me out? xP

Comment: Why are you calling this a "javascript document"? Do you mean an "object"?

Comment: yes... I'm a javascript newbie, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you read a book or a tutorial on javascript basics to be familiar with terms like JSON, arrays, functions, etc

[W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) is a great reference

However, the below sample code should fulfill your need

**Using Array**

```
//define array of JSON objects
//Each JSON object has 2 properties; key and value
var array = [{"key":"1", "value":"A"},{"key":"2", "value":"B"}];
//Search function
function Search(array, key){
for(i=0;i<array.length; i++)
    if(array[i].key === key)
        return array[i].value;
return null;
 }

//sample call
alert(Search(array, "2"));
```

**Using Dictionary**

```
//dictionary object
var dic = {1:"A",2:"B"};
function SearchDic(dic, key){
    return dic[key] ;//note we just pass the key to retreive the value
}
//sample call
alert(SearchDic(dic, 1));
```

Comment: I see, tyvm! So, there is no native function to accomplish this in an array?

Comment: If you are talking about array in particular, there is no other way as far as I know, as arrays can contain any types of objects including primitive types. So, you have to tell javascript what is the structure of your object to search for it. But **dictionary** is easier to search as per @MightyPork comment. you can change the function to be **return array[key];**

Comment: I have edited my answer to show both array and dictionary approaches. If this helps, please mark my answer as a valid answer and vote it up :)